# Run calculation of color only when user trigger the event

Tags: java, function, listener

I want to set some colors in the next method but I shouldn't do any calculation on THIS method/class because it is reprinted many times and it would make my application very slow:

```
void setStyle() {
    if (fake) {
        lineColor = EditorSettings.getInstance().getColorOfElement(FAKE_ELEMENT);
    }
    else if (important) {
        lineColor = EditorSettings.getInstance().getColorOfElement(IMPORTANT_ELEMENT);
    }
}
```

So the calculation that I want to do in another part of my code is:

```
EditorSettings.getInstance().getColorOfElement(FAKE_ELEMENT);
```

I would like to get the value of this calculation only when the user change the color of this element. I tried to store these calculations in a static block in another class but it didn't work. I read that maybe I could do it with a Listener but I have no idea how to. Could anyone help me?
Thanks :)

EDIT: Some more code --->

```
public class DiscoveryEditorSettings {

static {
    Color COLOR_FAKE_MESSAGE = DiscoveryEditorSettings.getInstance().getColorOfElement(FAKE_MESSAGE_KEY);
}
}
```

And then using this is not possible:

```
if (fake) {
        lineColor = DiscoveryEditorSettings.COLOR_FAKE_MESSAGE; 
    }
```

Comment: You should post more code, as is it's difficult to help you (showing the code calling `setStyle()` for example). Also you probably want to explain what you mean by "in a static block in another class but **it didn't work**"

Comment: Normally it should be possible to bind your values, what version of java are you using?

Comment: I'm using the last version of Java.
When I say that moving this code to a static block in another class didn't work I mean that it's not accesible from this part of the code.

Comment: I edited my question with some more code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a static block but a static (public) variable:

```
public class DiscoveryEditorSettings {
    public static Color COLOR_FAKE_MESSAGE = DiscoveryEditorSettings.getInstance().getColorOfElement(FAKE_MESSAGE_KEY);
}
```